# How to override FOSMessageBundle FormType or use a custom form in your own application MessageController?

Tags: validation, symfony, overriding, message-bundle

To override form type, I applied the similar approach which is for overriding templates. But that didn't work.That's why I'm asking here that is there any quick solution to use custom form for new threads? By the way I'm overriding MessageController already in my application.

Answer (score 0):

After doing lot of search, I didn't came across any solution. So, I decided to give it a try myself. And I was able to come up with a quick solution, which is given below.

I wanted to get control on new thread form and I also wanted to not take any subject, as username and body where my only required fields. To do that I did the following:

```
public function newThreadAction() {
    //$form = $this->container->get('fos_message.reply_form.factory')->create($thread);
    //the line below allows me to override the form as I want. As I commented the original one
    $form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->create(new \My\Bundle\Form\Type\NewThreadMessageFormType());

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        //process data according to your requirements
    }
    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSMessageBundle:Message:newThread.html.twig', array_merge(array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'data' => $form->getData()
                            )));
}
```

Note: the above method is from overridden class, and you can see how to override controller from this documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html

The other changes that I made to ensure that subject is never a required field, I override the FOSMessageBundle's `config/validation.xml` file. You can override it by placing the file in `App/Resources/FOSMessageBundle/config/validation.xml`. I opened it and then commented code for subject. Like and enjoy the solution if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Imran, your solution works, but as I understood you override method from vendor - so it is very bad practice.
It easy to resolve you task with this info:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html

So, you can change any classes in your own child bundle. And leave vendor bundle for futher updates.

Comment: You are right, I'm already overriding controller and files under Resources. But what was not working is the FormType override. That's what I required to have control on what is required and what isn't.